# Resolve Child class dependency using structure map

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

I am trying to resolve dependencies using structure map.How do I resolve all child class dependencies automatically by resgitering the base interface using structure map.

Conside the following example. I dont want to register UserHandler, officeHandler etc to the container separately. Is there a way I can register just the IHandler and resolve the handler automatically by passing IHandler, IHandler to get the respective handler.

```
public interface IHandler<T>
{
}

public class UserHandler : IHanlder<User>
{
}

public class OfficeHandler : IHandler<Office>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you:

```
var container = new Container(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Scan(s =>
    {
        s.TheCallingAssembly();
        s.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<UserHandler>();
        s.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandler<>));
    });
});
```

See [this article](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/18/advanced-structuremap-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types/) for further details.